# Put a div in red using ngStyle or ngClass

Tags: angular

I have a "div" and I would like to make its background red if the user has no parking space.

I tried to put a condition in a ngClass and a ngStyle without success

`[ngStyle]="{'background-color':this.account?.placeAttribute !== 'null' ? 'blue' : 'green' }"`

it does not matter, how?

if placeAttribute == null => red background

if placeAttribute == 2 => not red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do one of the following:

`[ngClass]="this.account.placeAttribute == null ? 'red-bg' : 'blue-bg'"`

OR

Make a method in your component like so:

```
getClassNames(){
    if (this.account.placeAttribute == null){
        let classes = {
            "red-bg": true
        }
        return classes;
    }
    else{
        let classes = { 
            "blue-bg": true
        }

        return classes;
    }
}
```

Then in the template:

`[ngClass]="getClassNames()"`

Obviously `red-bg` and `blue-bg` are css classes that have `background-color: red` and `background-color: blue` respectively

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
[ngStyle]="{ backgroundColor: this.account && this.account.placeAttribute ? 'blue' : 'green' }"
```

Comment: in fact, I would like that when this.account.place Attribute == null the background becomes red

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
[ngClass]="{
             'your-css-class': your-first-condition,
              'your-css-class': your-second-condition
           }"
```